# Related rates: Rocket launch. dy/dt = 0.8, y = 5, x =?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a vertical rocketlaunch.

x represents horizontal distance
y represents vertical distance

Right after launch:
y = 5 ;
dy/dt = 0.8

- Given: Distance between launch pad and radarstation: x1 = 3
- Asked for: Distance x from the rocket to the launchpad: x2 = ?

Using Pythagoras, Related rates and Calculus 1. Now how is that done?

Comment: Are you sure its done using Calculus 1 and not Calculus 100?

Comment: x represents horizontal distance
y represents vertical distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dt}=0.8$

Separate the variables $\int dy = \int 0.8 dt $

which gives

$y=0.8t+c$ where c is a constant.

at $t=0$, $y=5$ which implies $c=5$.

Therefore $y=0.8t+5$

The distance at any time is given by the Pythagorean theorem

Which is equal to

$\sqrt {((3)^ 2+(0.8t+5)^ 2}$

Hope this helped...

Comment: @Mollart Could you accept an answer if this helped? This is the way it works here, and is more nice to other people. :)

Comment: @Pedro: sry about that, just learnt that now, didn't get a notification by email on this.

Thanks for this, just figured out that in these types of problems x and y don't necessarily follow their respective axes, then it all makes sense and the answer is within reach!